# How do I escape characters in href of anchor tag

Tags: html, addslashes

I want to escape three characters these are

1. single quote (')
2. double quote (")
3. backslash ()

my href value is
`test.html?key="test' me'"&event=3`

I want to fix it as we do in `php` by calling `addslashes function`

```
<a href="test.html?key="test' me'"&event=3">test</a>
```

**NOTE: I need a dynamic way of doing it**

Comment: Note that `addslashes` is almost always a poor solution for any kind of escaping you need to do. Target environment specific functions are usually much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP function to take data and generate a properly encoded query string is `http_build_query`. You can then put it in a URL and then encode that using `htmlspecialchars` to insert it in a document.

```
<?php

    $base = "test.html";
    $query_data = Array(
        "key" => "\"test' me'\"",
        "event" => 3
    );
    $url = $base . "?" . http_build_query($query_data);
    $html_safe_url = htmlspecialchars($url);
?>

    <a href="<?= $html_safe_url ?>">test</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to URL encode your special characters.

A " would become %22

A ' would become %27

A \ would become %5C

Your anchor would have to be

```
test.html?key=%22test%27%20me%27%22&event=3
```

For more information on url encoding go to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp.

Answer (score 0):

Encode the Url maybe

```
<a href="test.html?key=%22test'%20me'%22&event=3">test</a>
```

Check out these url encodings at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

**ADDED:** 
`var $key ="\"test'\"";
 var $event = "3";
print '<a href="test.html?key=' . urlencode($key) .'&event=' . urlencode($event) .'">test</a>';`

I don't exactly know how php strings escape special characters like " but I suppose \" would work.

Comment: I need a dynamic way of doing it

Comment: Edited the answer. Please check with urlencode function and rawurlencode. Also if var $foo = "\"" is supposed to keep a double quotation as a string.
I'm not from a php background.