# How to Dial USSD with ionic framework

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am making a hybrid app with ionic framework and would like to dial USSDs. Dialing ordinary numbers (12345678) works no problem; but I am unable to dial USSDs (*556#); even after encoding the '#' character. Can someone please help me out?

```
<a ion-button href="tel:556" >call</a> // This dials the number - no problem here 
<a ion-button href="tel:*556#" >Call</a> // This does nothing <a ion-button href="tel:encodeURIComponent(*556#)" >Call</a> // This doesn't work either
```

It dials a USSD but I just don't think it dials exactly `*556#` as 
`"Error Performing Request, Unknown Error"` shows up on my screen. when I log `encodeURIComponent(*556#)`, I see `*556%23`

Comment: Please show us your code, what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried the following:
`
<a ion-button href="tel:556" >call</a> `// This dials the number - no problem here
`<a ion-button href="tel:*556#" >Call</a> `// This does nothing

`<a ion-button href="tel:encodeURIComponent(*556#)" >Call</a>` // This doesn't work either - It dials a USSD but I just don't think it dials exactly *556# as "Error Performing Request, Unknown Error" shows up on my screen. 

when I log encodeURIComponent(*556#), I see *556%23. 
@Ivaro18

Comment: edit the question and put formatted code in it, not in comments

Comment: also, see this answer
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/making-phone-call-from-app-href-tel-123/1968/16

Comment: @Marko , visited the link you sent... My normal calls work. What doesn't work is dialing USSDs. As soon as there's a ' * ' in front of the number, like (*556#) number doesn't dial.

Comment: try using HTML codes for * and #, i.e. http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm . Or, did you try to wrap the number in $scope and call it with ng-href?

Comment: @Marko, I will look into the ascii html codes now; but i've tried using javascript encodeURIComponent function; and still cannot get the USSD to run. I don't know if it's an ios specific issue; I'm yet to test on an android device; and I forgot specify that I'm using ionic2

Comment: the issue seems to me more like this for example than an ionic issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37695320/how-do-i-escape-charachters-in-href-of-anchor-tag

Comment: Because, if you look at this, the %23 stands for # http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me tell you that there are some emulators that work funny when it comes to certain devices. I have had clients facing some issues with that, the code worked fine but the emulator was at fault.

An emulator that I have used and did not have any issues is genymotion for android.

Coming to your code, let's say that we need to dial the number `123#456` this is what you need to have in your html

```
 <a href="tel:+123%23456" class="button button-positive">Call me 1</a>
 <button (click)="callIT('1-23#456')">call function</button>
```

note here that I am showing two methods, one by `href` and another by `click`

As you can see the first one will work out of the box as we have replaced `#` with `%23` in the `href` attribute.

In the second way, we are using a function called `callIT` and passing it the number.

So in your Javascript Code the function as follows

```
callIT(passedNumber){
    passedNumber = encodeURIComponent(passedNumber);
 window.location = "tel:"+passedNumber;
}
```

As shown we are using the `encodeURIComponent`

As you have mentioned in your code using `encodeURIComponent` in the href attribute will not work as it will be treated as a string.