# Using "href" to link a tiktok page. Tiktok URL use "@", but get error in cshtml

Tags: html, razor, hyperlink, tiktok

I want to link a tiktok page in a cshmt project using "href", but I think that because of the "@" that tiktok has by default it is giving error.

I tried to use the two syntaxes below, but in the browser the error appears: "Too many characters in the character literal" (example 1) and "The name "tiktok" does not exist in the current context"(example 2).

```
 <li>
   <a href="@('https://www.tiktok.com/@tiktok.example1?lang=en/')">
      <img src="/assets/img/social-tiktok.svg" alt="Tiktok Icon">
   </a>
 </li>
```

```
 <li>
   <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@tiktok.example2?lang=en/">
      <img src="/assets/img/social-tiktok.svg" alt="Tiktok Icon">
   </a>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37695320/how-do-i-escape-characters-in-href-of-anchor-tag) details ways to escape characters for html. If you don't need to do it dynamically, you can just replace '@' with `%40`.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, with that first error, `Too many characters in the character literal`, that is because when you stated `@()` you started writing in CS code. That's alright, but then that means that the way that `'` and `"` work changes. As you may know, in CS, single quotes (`'`) mark a type `char`, so `char exampleOne = 'a'` works, because a `char` can only be a single character, but `char exampleTwo = 'ab'` doesn't because a char may only be a single character length. So, `@('https://www.tiktok.com/@tiktok.example1?lang=en/')` should be `@("https://www.tiktok.com/@tiktok.example1?lang=en/")`, and that would work, see the following full example.

```
 <li>
   <a href="@("https://www.tiktok.com/@tiktok.example1?lang=en/")">
      <img src="/assets/img/social-tiktok.svg" alt="Tiktok Icon">
   </a>
 </li>
```

Then, the next error, `The name "tiktok" does not exist in the current context`, is because, like it says, there is no variable or method or anything that is called `tiktok`. This is because when you use `@` in a cshtml or razor file, it assumes you're going to use a CS keyword or variable, or something related. To escape this, you have a couple options. For ease of use, stating a double @ (`@@`) escapes the `@` use in cshtml/razor, and turns it into a single `@` char. However, if this is difficult for readability, you can use html escape character patterns, like `%40` as suggested by `pierrefondss` previously ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76212235/18640156) is a link to that).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

i have tried to replace @ with  `&#64;` and it works for me.